# File Tabs on the Main window for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create an add-in on Visual Studio 2012 to alter the display of the main window based upon the directory of the solution.One of the functionality that I would like this add-in to have it to alter the color of a file tab if the file is not in the same directory as the solution.[image]

As shown in the above picture, there are 4 different files open each with its own tab. My question is  if it is possible to access each tab so I can determine if the file is in a different directory from the solution and alter its appearance.